# Multi thread about NSOperationQueue iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading

I met a problem code example as below:

```
    #import "TestOperation.h"

@interface TestOperation()

@property (nonatomic, weak) id<someProtocol> delegate;
@property (nonatomic) NSOperationQueue *testQ;

@end

@implementation TestOperation

- (instancetype)initWithDelegate: (id<someProtocol>)delegate
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _delegate = delegate;
        _testQ = [[NSOperationQueue alloc]init];
        _testQ.maxConcurrentOperationCount = 1;
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)multiThreadQueueMethod {

    //po self.delegate

    [self.testQ addOperationWithBlock:^{
        //po self.delegate
    }];
}

@end
```

`multiThreadQueueMethod` is executed on another thread not main one, which is also not the testQ, when execute the first po after method called and before testQ new queue begin, the delegate is valid, but when execute the second delegate in testQ operation, the delegate is nil, so what's the problem?

Comment: It sounds as if the delegate object is released when the method returns (before your testQ block runs).

Comment: Who keeps a strong reference to  `TestOperation`?  It may have been deallocated before the block executes, causing the delegate to be nil.

Comment: Oh, my mistake, I set the object delegate reference to a local variable, and should released before testQ executed, thanks all.